# Calling Out Opera Mini for Site Redirect

Tags: jquery, redirect, opera-mini

I am working on a site with jQuery that seems to run beautifully on everything but Opera Mini, which chokes on pretty much any kind of Javascript-based interactivity I've worked with.  Is there a way to call out this mobile browser specifically for a website redirect without it calling out all Opera/Opera Mobile browsers as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect it by the presence of `Opera Mini` in the User-Agent header.

Comment: Yup, found this info literally two seconds after you answered.  Thanks so much!